# Excel-VBA Range.Find method error handling

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the range.find method to locate a cell with specific value in the first row.  When there's a match, the code works fine.  When there's no match, the code throws error as shown in screenshot below.

Is it normal that we need error handling for this method?  I thought it'd just return Null or Nothing.  Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: 1) Please post your code, not pictures of it. 2) It does return Nothing. 3) You need to use Set when assigning object variables `Set rg=...`

Comment: Thank you very much!  Newbie question - how do I determine which ones are object variables and require "set" command?  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, why it didn't throw error when it found match?  Thanks again!

Comment: Google it. Objects are workbooks, worksheets, ranges, charts etc. Your code will error for that reason whether or not the value is found.

Comment: You changed your question while I was posting the answer. I think Just numeric or string variables, including boolean (0,1) are not among objects.

Answer (score 2):

Use this. if you directly wanted to return column number of an empty range, it will show error.

```
Sub findtest() 
dim c as long
dim rng as range
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(What:="John Smith", _
        After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then c = rng.column : Debug.Print c
end sub
```